# Dropped and Contained Div jumps around outside of Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, containment

I'm a pretty new coder, going through a course for javascript and jquery. I stopped to play around with drag and drop features in jquery, and have gotten stumped on something.

Codepen - http://codepen.io/Allayna-1472610667/pen/ozvqNd

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    div {
      margin:auto;
    }

    #bigsquare { 
        width: 400px; 
        height: 400px; 
        background-color: aqua;
        border:2px solid #ccc; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #smallsquare {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: yellow;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }                    
  </style>
</head>
<body>            
  <div id="bigsquare">
    <p>Drop here</p>
  </div>                
  <div id="smallsquare">
    <p>Drop me in the box</p>
  </div>           
  <script type="text/javascript">               
     var dropped = false;

     $("#bigsquare").droppable( { 
        drop: function(event,ui) {
            $("#smallsquare").draggable("option", "containment", "#bigsquare");
            $("#smallsquare").css("background-color","green");
            $("#smallsquare").html("I am trapped now!");
            $("#bigsquare").css("background-color","red");
            $("#bigsquare").html("I have you now! BWAH HA HA!");
            dropped = true;
        }
     });


     $( "#smallsquare" ).draggable({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if(dropped == false) {
                $("#smallsquare").html("Don't let me get trapped!");    
            }
        }
     });
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This code without any margins or with floats, it works perfectly as it should: the little box can be dragged freely until dropped in the big one, then it is trapped in the big one. 
But if I dare apply the "margin:auto" to my divs to center my divs, the little box jumps outside the box that should be constraining it.